# emailid validation in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, regex

*how to validate this id in vb.det*

"enash.dine@gmail.com" using=ValidationExpression="^[\w-]+@[\w-]+.(com|net|org|edu|mil)$
this above code will not accept this id but this is a valid one
**for example**

```
<tr>
        <td align="right">
          <font face="Arial" size="2">Email Address:</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="email" Width="200px" MaxLength="60" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="emailReqVal" ControlToValidate="email" ErrorMessage="Email. "
            Display="Dynamic" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="12" runat="server">
        *
          </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="emailRegexVal" ControlToValidate="email" ErrorMessage="Email. "
            Display="Static" ValidationExpression="^[\w-]+@[\w-]+\.(com|net|org|edu|mil)$"
            Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="11" runat="server">
        Not a valid e-mail address.  Must follow email@host.domain.
          </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$
```

Answer (score 1):

The "." in the address is not part of the allowed characters specified by [\w-].

Try this instead: `^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.(com|net|org|edu|mil)$`

You should also escape the last "." since this would match any single character in regex, not necessarily a dot. Escaping it treats it as a literal dot as shown above.